# ProgressBar showing pourcentage

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to show the pourcentage within the ProgressBar but it shows 1% for one file spotted instead of showing 100%.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG9LS.png)

I understand why it shows me 1% and I know I've to change Label1Text to another value but I don't see which one would solve the problem.

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Start()
        Dim dossier = "C:\Users\adm\Desktop\A"
        Dim lesFichiers() As System.IO.FileInfo
        Dim dirinfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(dossier)
        lesFichiers = dirinfo.GetFiles("*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        For Each chaqueFichier In lesFichiers
            ProgressBar1.Maximum = lesFichiers.Length
                ProgressBar1.Value += 1
            Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.CenterToScreen()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        ProgressBar1.Increment(2)
        label1.Text = ProgressBar1.Value & " %"
        If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
            Timer1.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProgressBar1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ProgressBar1.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If you set `ProgressBar1.Maximum = 1` and increment it by `1 / lesFichiers.Length` then you can use `label1.Text = ProgressBar1.Value.ToString("P")`.  ([Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-percent-p-format-specifier).)

Comment: @Andrew Morton Hello! Thank you so much for your help. It worked and I've leaned something new today! :-)